Gophish email template link doesn't work
I downloaded gophish in a linux vps, more specifically in the /opt/gophish direcotry, i also created a systemd service (gophish.service)so i can close the file and the software can still be live. Also i changed the listen_url to "0.0.0.0:3333" in the config.json file. Finally i copy and page 1 template and 1 landing page from the internet to the gophish sections and clicked to checkbox called "Change Links to Point to Landing Page" to replace the links. Does anyone knows what may have happened? Thanks in advance!
The email template code
email template
when i click the link in the email template
the config.json file

thanks for the reply. I have created the template but the link doesnt navigate me to the landing page. Take a look:
email template
404 error

No - you give us no details. We need to know what happens, what error message, what your setup looks like and so forth

Take a look in the above images

Well, you still tell us nothing about how you've configured things.

ok, i downloaded gophish in a linux vps, more specifically in the /opt/gophish direcotry, i also created a systemd service so i can close the file and the software can still be live. Also i changed the listen_url to "0.0.0.0:3333" in the config.json file. Finally i copy and page 1 template and one landing page from the internet to the gophish sections and clicked to checkbox called "Change Links to Point to Landing Page" to replace the links. I hope I helped you this time

[Edit] your question. Describe the environment in as much detail as possible. Include where links points to and what config looks like. Read How to ask a good question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78273289/gophish-email-template-link-doesnt-work-correctly-when-it-is-pressed

Crossposted to StackOverflow

You listen on port 80, but your link specifies https. HTTPS defaults to port 443.

Ohhh, but because the gophish requires https i must change the port in the VPS?

Yes. And I would suggest hiring someone competent. Because your next question will probably be how you get rid of the tls certificate warning...

to change the :80 in the config.json file to port :443?. i have already made it. If you mean that
